# how to help typescript find self package types when import self

Tags: typescript

```json
// package.json
{
  name:"some-module"
  ....
}
```

```
// index.ts 
// same level w/ package.json
import module from 'some-module'
```

how to help typescript find the type of `some-module`, I've tried `paths` and `/// <reference />`, neither of them work